# Does Android Studio still compile unused imported libraries?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I have imports in a class file like this, is it necessary to remove all the unused imports or does Android already exclude them when building an APK? Would it improve compile time and performance to remove these from my classes?

[image]

Comment: Also, just to add, if you want remove all unused imports in your project just click on "app" in the project structure on the left and hit `ctrl+alt+O` for windows and `ctrl+option+O` for mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it necessary to remove all the unused imports or

Doing `Analyze - Code Cleanup` on Android Studio would be a good choice to make the project even clear for yourself! But, that's not mandatory.

> does Android
>   already exclude them when building an APK

I believe this won't happen when we export the project as an APK project. Why? Because this will probably make Android Studio in a huge misunderstanding or, reducing it's popularity because it's uses unused imports(Or perhaps, resources) for making APK files.

> Would it improve compile time and performance to remove these from my
>   classes?

Well sure. It will make the compiler easier to read and faster to compile used resources-imports classes.

Comment: Sometimes I forget that in the end, as much as Android Studio does for us, it is still an IDE that demands the responsibility of the programmer. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

use

```
minifyEnabled true
```

it will improve your app performance and make it use less resources. you can use it in release or debug

```
release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

  debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Comment: This obfuscates the application. However, this can be helpful too!